# Tkinter GUI Meant to Show and actively update a Number After Certain Conditions; Not showing

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been working on a program to do basic calculations based on inputs from a UI and present numbers gained from those calculations. The program returns no errors, but the expected labels containing the information do not show up when all conditions are met.

The program takes user inputs and turns into stats about a given ship. Stats - such as the acceleration in the example below - should appear below "Ship Specifications:". However, they do not.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
window = Tk()
window.title("Specifications Calculations")
window.geometry('600x4000')
frameprimaire = Frame(window)
frameprimaire.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
Cannavar = Canvas(frameprimaire)
Cannavar.pack(side = LEFT, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
CannavarFrame = Frame(Cannavar)
Cannavar.create_window((0,0), window = CannavarFrame, anchor = "nw")

# Relevant Vars, Tuples, and Dicts
LargeHydro = (7200000, 4820, 7.5)
Tiers = ("Base")
Sizes = ("Large")
Types = ("Hydrogen")
ThrusterStatsLarge = {
  "HBase":LargeHydro, 
}

# Relevant function 2, is used to create the final value
def speedcalc(weight, number, size, tier, type):
  InformationPackage = {}
  # Assembly is meant to produce a string that corresponds with a key in either ThrusterStatsLarge
  # or ThrusterStatsSmall; ex. Assembly = "HT2".
  Assembly = ""
  Assembly + type[0]
  Assembly + tier
  if size == "Large":
    for key, entry in ThrusterStatsLarge.items():
      if key == Assembly:
        # Infoset is a temporary storage of the relevant stats
        InfoSet = entry
      else:
        pass
  elif size == "Small":
    for key, entry in ThrusterStatsSmall.items():
      if key == Assembly:
        InfoSet = entry
      else:
        pass
  InformationPackage["Acceleration"] = (InfoSet[0] * number)/weight
  return InformationPackage

# Program kept returning the error "expected float, got '!text'"; this stopped that error.
if (TopEngines.get() and TopSize.get()) and (TopTier.get() and TopType.get()):
  Top = True
else: 
  Top = False

# Finally, a section of code that demonstrates the issue.
SpecificationsLabel = Label(CannavarFrame, text = "Ship Specifications:")
SpecificationsLabel.pack(side = RIGHT)

ShipWeightLabel = Label(CannavarFrame, text = "Enter ship weight.")
SWT = Text(CannavarFrame, height = 1, width = 30)
ShipWeight.set(SWT)
ShipWeightLabel.pack(side = TOP)
SWT.pack(side = TOP)

TopThrusterLabel = Label(CannavarFrame, text = "Enter amount of top thrusters.")
TTDM = OptionMenu(CannavarFrame, TopSize, *Sizes)
TTTDM = OptionMenu(CannavarFrame, TopTier, *Tiers)
TTETDM = OptionMenu(CannavarFrame, TopType, *Types)
TTN = Text(CannavarFrame, height = 1, width = 5)
TopEngines.set(TTN)
TopThrusterLabel.pack(side = TOP)
TTDM.pack(side = TOP)
TTTDM.pack(side = TOP)
TTETDM.pack(side = TOP)
TTN.pack(side = TOP)
if Top:
  # TopAcceleration should show up below SpecificationsLabel; however, it does not.
  TopThrusterInformation = speedcalc(ShipWeight.get(), TopEngines.get(), TopSize.get(), TopTier.get(), TopType.get())
  TopAcceleration = Label(CannavarFrame, text = f"Top Acceleration: {TopThrusterInformation[0]}")
  TopAcceleration.pack(side = RIGHT)
else:
  pass

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are setting the `Top` variable, and adding the additional information label based on it, *exactly once* - during the startup of your program.  You've done absolutely nothing to update it when the conditions change.  You need to move all that into a function, and arrange to call it when conditions change - via the `command=` option of each relevant OptionMenu, for example.

Comment: I cannot say that I am not embarrassed from this overlook, though your advice has helped immensely.

I've modified the program to have `Top` and other booleans assigned in functions. I've also shifted the if/else conditional below the block of code for making the UI elements into a function, making it the command; nesting the call for updating `Top` inside. Again, thank you greatly.

A new issue has risen in the form of `expected floating-point number, got '!frame.!canvas.!frame.!text2` in the if/else for if `Top` is true or not; but that is not something to add to this question.